# ES query to match all elements in array

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-7

So I got this document with a
nested array that I want to filter with this query.

I want ES to return all documents where all items have changes = 0 and that only.
If document has even a single item in the list with a change = 1, that's discarded.

Is there any way I can achieve this starting from the query I have already wrote? Or should I use a script instead?

DOCUMENTS:

```
{
    "id": "abc",
    "_source" : {
        "trips" : [
            {
                "type" : "home",
                "changes" : 0
            },
            {
                "type" : "home",
                "changes" : 1
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
        "id": "def",
        "_source" : {
            "trips" : [
                {
                    "type" : "home",
                    "changes" : 0
                },
                {
                    "type" : "home",
                    "changes" : 0
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

QUERY:

```
GET trips_solutions/_search

    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "id": {
                  "value": "abc"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "trips",
                "query": {
                  "range": {
                    "trips.changes": {
                      "gt": -1,
                      "lt": 1
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
{
            "id": "def",
            "_source" : {
                "trips" : [
                    {
                        "type" : "home",
                        "changes" : 0
                    },
                    {
                        "type" : "home",
                        "changes" : 0
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

**Elasticsearch version: 7.6.2**

Already read this answers but they didn't help me:
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-match-all-item-in-nested-array/163873
[ElasticSearch: How to query exact nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46104158/elasticsearch-how-to-query-exact-nested-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, if you filter by `id: abc`, you obviously won't be able to get `id: def` back.

Second, due to the nature of `nested` fields which are treated as separate subdocuments, you cannot query for all `trips` that have the `changes` equal to 0 -- the connection between the individual trips is lost and they "don't know about each other".

What you *can* do is return only the trips that matched your nested query using `inner_hits`:

```
GET trips_solutions/_search
{
  "_source": "false",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "inner_hits": {},
            "path": "trips",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "trips.changes": {
                  "value": 0
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The easiest solution then is to dynamically save this nested info on a parent object [like discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098750/8160318) and using range/term query on the resulting array.

---

EDIT:

Here's how you do it using [`copy_to`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html) onto the doc's top level:

```
PUT trips_solutions
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "trips_changes": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "trips": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "changes": {
            "type": "integer",
            "copy_to": "trips_changes"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`trips_changes` will be an array of numbers -- I presume they're integers but [more types are available](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/number.html).

Then syncing a few docs:

```
POST trips_solutions/_doc
{"trips":[{"type":"home","changes":0},{"type":"home","changes":1}]}

POST trips_solutions/_doc
{"trips":[{"type":"home","changes":0},{"type":"home","changes":0}]}
```

And finally querying:

```
GET trips_solutions/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "trips",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "trips.changes": {
                  "value": 0
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "source": "doc.trips_changes.stream().filter(val -> val != 0).count() == 0"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note that we first filter normally using the nested term query to narrow down our search context (scripts are slow so this is useful). We then check if there are any non-zero `changes` in the accumulated top-level changes and reject those that apply.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response! Unfortunatly is not the option that fits best my needs! I need to filter every item cause the array is like a "packet" to me so I would like to discard the document if the "packet" doesn't suit all the conditions. 

Do you know if a script could help me?

Comment: Updated my answer -- Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much Joe! You've been so kind!

Comment: No prob! Feel free to accept & upvote the answer ;)